# C# DB application Access DB Create Table issue

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am creating an application that writes to an access database and I keep getting an error when executing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().

The error is Syntax Error in Field Definition.

Line: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Below is my code:

```
            createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE [Payments] (" +
                         "[PaymentData] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, [PaySource] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, [LastStatus] bit NOT NULL, [Remit] bit NOT NULL, [ConvenienceFee] DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL, " +
                         "[PaymentID] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, [PaymentMode] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, [PaymentEntryDate] DATETIME NOT NULL, [InvoicedAmount] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [PaymentAmount] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                         "[PaymentStatus] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [PaymentNote] VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL);";

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + fileName + ";Persist Security Info=True");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandText = createTableSQL;
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
            result = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            result = false;
        }
```

Comment: What version of Access are you using? If my memory serves me well, Access has 2 types of text fields - text & memo, not varchar.

Comment: Are you able to run the statement directly in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access DDL does not support `VARCHAR(MAX)` in a field definition.  Use `MEMO` there instead.

I tested your `CREATE TABLE` statement with that change in Access 2010.  This created the table without error ...

```vb
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "CREATE TABLE [Payments] (" & _
    "[PaymentData] MEMO NOT NULL, [PaySource] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, [LastStatus] bit NOT NULL, [Remit] bit NOT NULL, [ConvenienceFee] DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL, " & _
    "[PaymentID] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, [PaymentMode] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, [PaymentEntryDate] DATETIME NOT NULL, [InvoicedAmount] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [PaymentAmount] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " & _
    "[PaymentStatus] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [PaymentNote] VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue

```
createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE [Payments] (" +
                     "[PaymentData] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, [PaySource] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, [LastStatus] bit NOT NULL, [Remit] bit NOT NULL, [ConvenienceFee] **DECIMAL(6,2)** NOT NULL, " +
                     "[PaymentID] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, [PaymentMode] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, [PaymentEntryDate] DATETIME NOT NULL, [InvoicedAmount] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [PaymentAmount] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                     "[PaymentStatus] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [PaymentNote] VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL);";

    try
    {
        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + fileName + ";Persist Security Info=True");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        cmd.CommandText = createTableSQL;
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
        result = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        result = false;
    }
```

The decimal datatype doesn't work in the access version I am using.

Comment: Varchar works. The issue was VARCHAR(MAX) and DECIMAL